# Cost Effective/Performance Raid Setup For Video Production

Tags: windows, raid, raid-controller

I just built a new machine based on an Asus x99a/3.1 motherboard and 5820 cpu. I do video production and web development. Im running windows 10 and my main os drive is a samsung 950 pro 512mb (Probably overkill).

I want to be able to edit 4k video on my machine using premiere pro. I currently have 2 ssds in addition to my system drive and a hd. 1 ssd for storage of current video I'm working on and 1 as a scratch disk and the 4tb drive is where I archive.

The problem I'm running into is all the raw video storage. I currently shoot every thing in 1080i5994. I'm shooting an event and coming home with 250gb in video that I need to edit, archive, produce tv shows with and burn to dvd/bluray for sale. I shoot about 3 events a month right now and am starting to run out of space on my 4tb internal drive.

I think the way I want to go is with a raid array in my system of 4 - 4tb western digital black drives. Then for backup I will get either an external nas to copy the data to or just use external usb3 drives then take them to the bank or somewhere safe to store them.

I dont have a lot to spend, probably about 1k for now but I will expand as I grow. I was thinking I would just do a Raid5 array in windows with the 4 4tb drives giving me 12tb of working storage and then I would back up outside of the machine. Or should I get a pcie card of some sort? I was looking at [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BUC3N74). I'm not entirely sure which way would be the most cost effective vs performant. Am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: Any software RAID5 (or semi-software motherboard-based fake-RAID) is going to have performance issues. If you want RAID5, get a real hardware RAID card. (FYI, the PCI card you linked is not RAID5-capable.)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to what T.J.L. said (i completely agree with him). Software/MB raid is bad!!! Unfortunately for you, any solution that you choose that is going to be sufficient is going to be expensive.

So here are your choices as I see them:
This card has some good recommendations: [http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816117153&Tpk=Intel%20RS2BL040&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-VigLink2-*-na-*-na-_-na&cm_sp=&AID=10446076&PID=3821802&SID=imc5dvz3r0000a1700053](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816117153&Tpk=Intel%20RS2BL040&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-VigLink2-_-na-_-na-_-na&cm_sp=&AID=10446076&PID=3821802&SID=imc5dvz3r0000a1700053)

keep in mind its Intel so there should be no issues with setup. (or choose a similar card, i know they are expensive, but you get what you pay for) Its pretty much a carbon copy of an LSI card but with Intel firmware. You should get a UPS if you go this route!!!!!!

For a NAS I would recommend Synology DiskStation DS1515+ 
I have a DS216+ (I love it, a lot of features).
It is easy to expand and you can easily add or upgrade drives in it.

Another option is to get a Synology DS1515+ or 1815+ and map a network drive to your PC. Now this is going to be a bit slower, but you can bridge all the ports on the NAS to work together to get you more throughput + a 1Gb switch or connection should work (no promises, you will need to test this for yourself). Be sure to get the "+" versions. the others are underpowered in my opinion.

Comment: I dont mind spending that for that card if its worth it. The question I keep coming back to though is, will it let me edit 4k video from the array with decent performance. If I'm going to have to copy the files to an ssd to do the editing then I might as well just skip the raid array and use independent drives for storage and then copy the files to the ssd for editing then archive when finished.

Comment: @ahackney  The more hard drives you add, the faster the performance is up to the limit of the CPU on the RAID card.  You should really consider RAID 6.  As a general rule of thumb you should be able to get 90%, possible more, of the max read speed of each drive.  So 4 drives 100mb/s =400mb/s*0.9 is 360mb/s.  Write speeds are slower, say 80mb/s per drive, on all hdd, but it follows the same general rule, but the CPU on the RAID card will eventually cause you to top out.